# ffmpeg batch overlay Error: "Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_overlay_0"

Tags: ffmpeg, windows, command-line

I am trying to create a batch file to run this script to add a watermark on each file in a folder

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" output.mov
```

The script above works fine but when I try to run the batch I get Error: "Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_overlay_0"

```
@echo off
REM Add watermark to video batch
for %%a in (*.mov) do ( ffmpeg "%%a" -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" "output\%%~na.mov"
)
pause
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot `-i`. Try:

```
@echo off
REM Add watermark to video batch
for %%a in (*.mov) do ( ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" "output\%%~na.mov"
)
pause
```

Comment: So stupid. That did it. Thank you very much.

Comment: You should mark this answer as the solution, otherwise the question will keep popping out in the homepage :)